# How to integrate Mailchimp into wordpress using Elementor

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, subscription, elementor

I've a website built in wordpress with Elementor.
And I've created a mailchimp account and I've updated the API key from Mailchimp to wordpress in the settings.

So, now how can I integrate the the subscribe form in elementor in wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Open the page that has you form widget and select the form widget.

On the left of the page, on the form option, open ACTIONS AFTER SUBMIT.

Select MAILCHIMP to add it to the list of actions.

A new option for MAILCHIMP will show just bellow. Open it.

On API Key, select CUSTOM

Paste on the CUSTOM API FIELD the api key you copied from Mailchimp site.

Select the final details of how you want it to be saved on the list.

Define the key mapping, defining the email from the form field to the email field of mailchimp.

**Test it.**